# How do I simply run an ubuntu touch app from the terminal?

Tags: command-line, ubuntu-touch, application-development, ubuntu-sdk, qml

I've got a qml file and I just want to ssh to the phone and do

```
qmlscene myfile.qml
```

Is it possible without doing all that stuff with SDK and packages? Just vim and some simple commands that can fit into person's memory.

Comment: Did you try my `qmlscene` argument?

Comment: Yes, I tried, thank you. I haven't replied because it looks like a hack.

Comment: Without a click package this is the easiest way to run a single qml file on the device

Comment: Considering that `qmlscene` is a development tool, the use of `--desktop_file_hint` is perfectly valid to quickly validate your qml file on the device.  If the solution below worked your you, could you vote/accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you already have your qml file on the phone, it's pretty easy. All you have to do is to call `qmlscene` with an extra argument.

1. Start a connection from your desktop/laptop with `phablet-shell`.
2. Run `qmlscene` with `--desktop_file_hint`, example:

   ```
   $ qmlscene --desktop_file_hint=/usr/share/applications/dialer-app.desktop $HOME/Documents/myfile.qml
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Wasn't so simple on OTA 10.1 (Ubuntu 15.04), BQ E5, with `phablet-shell` ssh connection, I had to issue *this* one-liner command line to get it to run:

```
APP_ID=com.ubuntu.clock_clock_3.7.456 \
QML2_IMPORT_PATH=/usr/share/click/preinstalled/com.ubuntu.clock/3.7.456/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf \
QML_IMPORT_TRACE=1 \
/usr/bin/qmlscene \
--desktop_file_hint=/usr/share/click/preinstalled/com.ubuntu.clock/3.7.456/share/applications/ubuntu-clock-app.desktop \
/usr/share/click/preinstalled/com.ubuntu.clock/3.7.456/share/qml/ubuntu-clock-app.qml
```

Note, when you run the app like this, all of its output is dumped to the calling terminal, while there is nothing in `~/.cache/upstart/application-click-com.ubuntu.clock_clock_3.7.456.log`. Should start also when the phone is sleeping, and it blocks in terminal, and Ctrl-C will terminate it (and its window on device). The `QML2_IMPORT_PATH` solves the:

```
file:///usr/share/click/preinstalled/com.ubuntu.clock/3.7.456/share/qml/ubuntu-clock-app.qml:22 module "Alarm" is not installed
file:///usr/share/click/preinstalled/com.ubuntu.clock/3.7.456/share/qml/ubuntu-clock-app.qml:20 module "WorldClock" is not installed
```

... see [Bug #1338979 “Invalid qmlscene invocation -- invalid option -- 'I'” : Bugs : notes-app](https://bugs.launchpad.net/notes-app/+bug/1338979)

Note that without the `--desktop_file_hint`, you'll get:

```
Loading module: 'libubuntu_application_api_touch_mirclient.so.3.0.0'
UbuntuClientIntegration: connection to Mir server failed. Check that a Mir server is
running, and the correct socket is being used and is accessible. The shell may have
rejected the incoming connection, so check its log file
Aborted
```