# Loading module: 'libubuntu_application_api_touch_mirclient.so.3.0.0' This plugin does not support propagateSizeHints()

Tags: ubuntu-touch, nexus-4, mir, click-packages

I'm getting this error when trying to build my click package for my nexus 4 phone. This issue does not exist when I build for the desktop:

```
Loading module: 'libubuntu_application_api_touch_mirclient.so.3.0.0'
This plugin does not support propagateSizeHints()
```

The full error is here:

[image]

I don't know how to troubleshoot this. Any idea what this is saying?

Comment: It's not necessarily because of that warning. Try to run it manually using `qmlscene` to see more logs.

Comment: @Velkan Can you run qmlscene on your phone? I don't get any errors running this on my desktop.

Comment: Pure QML apps are launched through `qmlscene` by the GUI environment. To run from terminal: `$ qmlscene --desktop_file_hint=/usr/share/applications/dialer-app.desktop $HOME/Documents/myfile.qml` ([from here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/642444/how-do-i-simply-run-an-ubuntu-touch-app-from-the-terminal))

Comment: @Velkan I did that: http://i.imgur.com/ycwvKgy.png Basically the same error. I tried running another app in qml scene already installed on my phone, and got the same error :/

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/12699045/ -- This is the coredump

Comment: And a qml file that has just a rectangle in it runs? (through terminal with `--desktop_file_hint=/usr/share/applications/dialer-app.desktop`)

Comment: I made a bunch of sample projects from the sdk using the templates. Every one of them failed to launch, except the app that uses .qmlproject as its project file.  As to your command there, that fails as well:  http://i.imgur.com/8CtFNLG.png

Comment: There is no `something.qml` file on that command line. Without the file name I've got the same error. So, the install scripts are not ok.

Comment: do I have to find the main.qml my app is using, and navigate it there then? I'll try that.

Answer (score 1):

There is something similar. Bug report for Calculator app:

[http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~gang65/ubuntu-calculator-app/ubuntu-calculator-app-install-fix/revision/218#app/CMakeLists.txt](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/%7Egang65/ubuntu-calculator-app/ubuntu-calculator-app-install-fix/revision/218#app/CMakeLists.txt)

> Tested on multiple devices (arale, krillin running rc-proposed) and krillin running retail OTA-5.
>
> Starting calculator results in the launch window, then the app dies without ever drawing the calculator window.
>
> The app launches fine on the desktop.
>
> Something broke between r182 (currently in the store) and r217.
>
> Log contains:-

```
phablet@ubuntu-phablet:~/.cache/upstart$ cat application-click-com.ubuntu.calculator_ubuntu-calculator-app_2.0.217.log
libust[27746/27749]: Error: Error opening shm /lttng-ust-wait-5-32011 (in get_wait_shm() at lttng-ust-comm.c:958)
libust[27746/27749]: Error: Error opening shm /lttng-ust-wait-5-32011 (in get_wait_shm() at lttng-ust-comm.c:958)
libust[27746/27748]: Error: Error opening shm /lttng-ust-wait-5 (in get_wait_shm() at lttng-ust-comm.c:958)
libust[27746/27748]: Error: Error opening shm /lttng-ust-wait-5 (in get_wait_shm() at lttng-ust-comm.c:958)
Loading module: 'libubuntu_application_api_touch_mirclient.so.3.0.0'
UbuntuWindow - regular geometry
UbuntuWindow - regular geometry
UbuntuWindow - regular geometry
This plugin does not support propagateSizeHints()
```

Fix Committed to branch (rev 218): [lp:~gang65/ubuntu-calculator-app/ubuntu-calculator-app-install-fix (rev 218)](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/%7Egang65/ubuntu-calculator-app/ubuntu-calculator-app-install-fix/revision/218)

diff:

```
=== modified file 'app/CMakeLists.txt'
--- app/CMakeLists.txt  2015-07-20 19:23:20 +0000
+++ app/CMakeLists.txt  2015-07-31 11:54:58 +0000
@@ -3,14 +3,8 @@
   add_custom_target(ubuntu-calculator-app_QMlFiles ALL SOURCES ${QML_JS_FILES})
 endif(NOT "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}" STREQUAL "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}")
 
-if(CLICK_MODE)
-  install(FILES graphics/${ICON_FILE} DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX})
-  install(FILES ${MAIN_QML} DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX})
-else (CLICK_MODE)
-  install(FILES graphics/${ICON_FILE} DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/${UBUNTU-CALCULATOR-APP_DIR})
-  install(FILES ${MAIN_QML} DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/${UBUNTU-CALCULATOR-APP_DIR})
-endif(CLICK_MODE)
-
+install(FILES graphics/${ICON_FILE} DESTINATION ${UBUNTU-CALCULATOR-APP_DIR})
+install(FILES ${MAIN_QML} DESTINATION ${UBUNTU-CALCULATOR-APP_DIR})
 
 add_subdirectory(engine)
 add_subdirectory(graphics)

=== modified file 'manifest.json.in'
--- manifest.json.in    2015-07-09 20:39:32 +0000
+++ manifest.json.in    2015-07-31 11:54:58 +0000
@@ -4,7 +4,7 @@
     "description": "Powerful and easy to use calculator.",
     "framework": "ubuntu-sdk-14.10",
     "hooks": {
-        "@APP_HARDCODE@": {
+        "calculator": {
             "apparmor": "@APP_HARDCODE@.apparmor",
             "desktop": "@CMAKE_INSTALL_DATADIR@/applications/ubuntu-calculator-app.desktop"
         }
```

Comment: It may be because I am using the wrong channel. Popey recommended me using an aquaris channel for the nexus 4 [which is what I have been using], where dobey is now suggesting I try ubuntu-touch/rc-proposed/ubuntu instead. I'll let you know how it goes.

Comment: And... nothing. I'll take a look at this answer then :)

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by creating a new project in the SDK, using the template:

[image]

And transferring my project files to this project. While not a solution to the bug, this was by my metric the quickest workaround that allowed me to get back to work.