# Is qml from the terminal supposed to work on OTA-10.2

Tags: ubuntu-touch, qml

Context: Meizu PRO 5 w/ UbuntuTouch OTA-10.2 (unboxed today).  Developer Mode, and a rw filesystem.

Question, qml and qmlscene segfault, and have broken symlinks:

```
phablet@ubuntu-phablet:~$ qmlscene
Loading module: 'libubuntu_application_api_touch_mirclient.so.3.0.0'
UbuntuClientIntegration: connection to Mir server failed. Check that a Mir server is
running, and the correct socket is being used and is accessible. The shell may have
rejected the incoming connection, so check its log file
Aborted
phablet@ubuntu-phablet:~$ export MIR_SOCKET=/var/run/mir_socket
phablet@ubuntu-phablet:~$ qmlscene
Loading module: 'libubuntu_application_api_touch_mirclient.so.3.0.0'
Segmentation fault
phablet@ubuntu-phablet:~$ qml 
qml: could not exec '/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/qt5/bin/qml': No such file or directory
```

Note, MIR_SOCKET seems to not be set by default.

One last thing: there should be a StackExchange tag for OTA-10 (etc)

Comment: What are you trying to do that you need to run qmlscene from the terminal or set the root filesystem to read/write mode? You shouldn't need to do either of those things on the phone.

Comment: I'm wanting to see if I can get node.qml working on the thing.

Comment: A workaround still works? http://askubuntu.com/questions/642444/how-do-i-simply-run-an-ubuntu-touch-app-from-the-terminal

Answer (score 0):

You cannot run qmlscene from the terminal like that. Applications are run under confinement.

Also, you should not set the device root filesystem to read/write mode. It will only result in problems with updates in the future.